# Create plugin for IntelliJ IDEA. Plugin is incompatible with this installation

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, plugins, android-studio-3.0, intellij-plugin

I create a plugin for IntelliJ IDEA and I want it to run on Android Studio and other products based on IDEA.

I use [gradle-intellij-plugin](https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin)
and have such settings:

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.10'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.intellij" version "0.2.17"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.2.10"
}
group pluginGroup
version pluginVersion

apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.intellij'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'


intellij {
    version 'IC-2017.3'
    plugins 'git4idea'
    pluginName "plugin name"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    //...
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

plugins.xml

```
<idea-plugin>
   ...
   <idea-version since-build="143.379"/>
   <depends>com.intellij.modules.lang</depends>
   <depends>com.intellij.modules.vcs</depends>
   <depends>Git4Idea</depends>
   ...
</idea-plugin>
```

On IntelliJ IDEA is installed without errors. 
When install on Android Studio 3.0.1 there is an error

> Plugin 'plugin name' is incompatible with this installation

How to fix the error?

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problem too and I solved it from plugin.xml , you can also find the solution easily in plugin.xml .

In plugin.xml , you can see this :

```
<!-- please see http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started/build_number_ranges.html for description -->
<idea-version since-build="173.0"/>
<!-- please see http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started/plugin_compatibility.html
   on how to target different products -->
<!-- uncomment to enable plugin in all products
<depends>com.intellij.modules.lang</depends>
-->
```

we can get two links :

1. http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started/build_number_ranges.html
2. http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started/plugin_compatibility.html

I solve the problem by the 1st link , I think the 2nd link is also worth to collect .

Go into the 1st link , and scroll down you will see:
[image]

So just change

> idea-version since-build="173.0"

to

> idea-version since-build="141"

Now you can retry to prepare your plugin .

Answer (score 0):

Сhanged the settings and it works for me

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.10'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.intellij" version "0.2.17"
}
group pluginGroup
version pluginVersion

apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.intellij'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'idea'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

intellij {
    version '2017.3'
    plugins 'git4idea'
    pluginName "plugin name"
    updateSinceUntilBuild false
    type 'IC'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    compile("com.taskadapter:redmine-java-api:3.1.0") {
        exclude group: "org.slf4j"
    }

//    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

plugin.xml

```
<idea-version since-build="141.177"/>
<depends>com.intellij.modules.lang</depends>
<depends>Git4Idea</depends>
```